Spring Cloud Kubernetes ConfigMap in bootstrap phase
I have an Sprint Boot 3 application, and I use property placeholders in bootstrap.yml, like:
spring:
  cloud:
    service-registry:
      auto-registration:
        enabled: ${my-spring-cloud.enabled}

This placeholder currently is resolved from Configuration, which is registered as a Bootstrap configuration:
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=com.example.MyConfigurator

On its turn, MyConfigurator is annotated with @PropertySource, pointing to property file with my-spring-cloud.enabled
Everything runs as expected, bootstrap properties are resolved (I run it with spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true)
Now, I want to move this setup to ConfigMap in Kubernetes. So I created ConfigMap with my-spring-cloud.enabled, and I see it's resolved in application context, but not in bootstrap context, meaning when I inject with @Value('${my-spring-cloud.enabled}') to some bean, I get what I expect, but bootstrap.yaml placeholders are not resolved.
 Not enough variable values available to expand 'my-spring-cloud.enabled'

Is there a way to replicate the same behaviour with ConfigMap? I see that KubernetesBootstrapConfiguration is registered as BootstrapConfiguration as well, so I expect it to behave in the same way
I expect that placeholder in bootstrap.yml will be resolved with values from ConfigMap, i.e. :
spring:
  cloud:
    service-registry:
      auto-registration:
        enabled: ${my-spring-cloud.enabled}


hmm, I don't think this is possible. In the bootstrap phase we read config maps to create PropertySources, that allows you to inject values. It seems to me this is not possible
